# Send sms notify message to user when his/her account locked, how can i do that in C#

Tags: c#, sms, twilio, botframework, proactive

Bot Info 
SDK : C# 
Active Channels: SMS (Twilio) 
Bot version: v4.4.3

Issue Description:
I'd like to be able to send proactive messages through SMS messages. When a user's account locked, i have that person's phone number, and i want to send a notify message like "your account is locked, please do something." Is this possible?
i checked the documentation about proactive message, which is get the "ConversationReference" through "activity", i don't know with the phone number, can i create a "ConversationReference" object, and how to tell bot about the phone number through notify controller.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, unlike most channels, you can construct a conversation reference without having to have the user message the bot first since you know the user's number and you have the bot's number. Take a look at the code snippet below. You can send a proactive message to a phone number by sending a get request to `http://localhost:3978/api/notify/+1##########`

```cs
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication;

[HttpGet("{number}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string number)
{
    MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl("https://sms.botframework.com/"); 

    var conversationReference = new ConversationReference {
        User = new ChannelAccount { Id = number },
        Bot = new ChannelAccount { Id = "<BOT_NUMBER>" },
        Conversation = new ConversationAccount { Id = number },
        ServiceUrl = "https://sms.botframework.com/"
    };

    await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, BotCallback, default(CancellationToken));

    // Let the caller know proactive messages have been sent
    return new ContentResult()
    {
        Content = "<html><body><h1>Proactive messages have been sent.</h1></body></html>",
        ContentType = "text/html",
        StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
    };
}

private async Task BotCallback(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("proactive hello");
}
```

For more details on sending proactive messages, take a look at the [Proactive Message sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!!! it's working. I have one more question. Is that possible i send the user's phone number when i call "http://localhost:3978/api/notify"? If it possible, how can i resolve the number.

Comment: I'm glad you found my answer helpful. If you wouldn't mind marking it as an accepted answer, I would appreciate it. I've updated my answer to include the users number as a URL parameter for the request.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you don't already have a conversation reference from a previous conversation then the documentation doesn't seem clear on how you would start a conversation. In this case, it might be easier to [send the user the SMS message using the Twilio API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages?code-sample=code-send-an-sms-message-2&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=5.x) directly.